# Are almost everywhere continuous functions borel measurable?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Consider $f:\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$. Assume that $f({\bf x},t)$ is continuous at ${\bf x}$ and continuous almost everywhere at $t$. Is such a function Borel measurable? Is there any book that states that such result, or a set of results by which it can be derived?

Comment: Think about $g : \mathbb R \to [0,1]$, where $g(t) = 1$ on a set $A$ and $g(t) = 0$ elsewhere.  In particular, take $A$ to be a strategic subset of the Cantor set.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Unfortunately I just started styudying measure theory and at the moment I don't have enough knowledge to prove the result on my own. Ideally I would like to study it from a book

Comment: The answer is no.  If "almost everywhere" is with respect to Lebesgue measure, then the most you can hope for is Lebesgue measurable, not Borel measurable.  Even in the case where $f(\mathbf{x},t) = g(t)$.

Comment: Thank you again for this further clarification. I was wondering if the result would be true if the set of discontinuos point is countable